# empty(func($var)) triggers a "Can't use function return value" error

Tags: php, wordpress

This code:

```
if(  get_theme_mod('enable_content_background_color') && empty( get_theme_mod('content_background_image') ) ) {
         $custom .= " .site-content {
               background-image: none;
          }"."\n";
```

Triggers this error:

> Can't use function return value in write context in /home3/*******/public_html/*******/wp-content/themes/outliner/includes/styles.php on line 41

I wonder why?

Comment: i think your extension of file is wrong. It should be styles.css.php

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the `empty()` function only supports variables. If you look at the [PHP.net Doc for the empty method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) you'll see;

> Note:
>   Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

You'll need to do something like;

```
$contentBgImage = get_theme_mod('content_background_image');    
if( get_theme_mod('enable_content_background_color') && empty($contentBgImage ) ) { 
//code
}
```